# Hide show error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist and it is very simple. You click the button to go further you have error if you don't select nothing from DDL. But how i do to not appear the error when the user choose something from the DDL?

Here is the markup:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" CssClass="jump">
     <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>  
     <asp:ListItem Text="Coupé" Value="Coupé" />
     <asp:ListItem Text="Cabriolet" Value="Cabriolet" />
     <asp:ListItem Text="Pickup" Value="Pickup" />   
     <asp:ListItem Text="Kombi" Value="Kombi" />   
     <asp:ListItem Text="Kombi-Coupé" Value="Kombi-Coupé" />  
     <asp:ListItem Text="Minibuss" Value="Minibuss" />
     <asp:ListItem Text="Sedan" Value="Sedan" />    
     <asp:ListItem Text="Skåpbil" Value="Skåpbil" />
     <asp:ListItem Text="SUV" Value="SUV" />                      
     <asp:ListItem Text="Övrig" Value="Övrig" /> 
</asp:DropDownList>
<p id="err" runat="server"></p>
```

and code-behind:

```
if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 0)
{
    err.InnerHtml = "<span style='font: normal bold 11px/100% Arial, Verdana, Sans-Serif; color: Red'>Du måste välja Fordonstyp!</span>";
    return;
}
```

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: you have to have a postback. have you considered adding a `Validator`?

Comment: There should be a badge for most contradictory title of the day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As simple as this:

```
err.InnerHtml = "";
if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        err.InnerHtml = "<span style='font: normal bold 11px/100% Arial, Verdana, Sans-Serif; color: Red'>Du måste välja Fordonstyp!</span>";
        return;
    }
```

This will hide the error by default, then show it only if needed.

**Edit**: to support more than one drop down wrap it nicely with a function first:

```
private bool HandleDropDownError(DropDownList oDDL, HtmlGenericControl oErrorControl, string strErrorText)
{
    oErrorControl.InnerHtml = "";
    if (oDDL.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        oErrorControl.InnerHtml = "<span style='font: normal bold 11px/100% Arial, Verdana, Sans-Serif; color: Red'>" + strErrorText + "</span>";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now just use the same error label to show error for any drop down, and have such code in the `Page_Load`:

```
if (!HandleDropDownError(DropDownList1, err, "Du måste välja Fordonstyp!"))
    return;
if (!HandleDropDownError(DropDownList2, err, "Du måste välja matta!"))
    return;
if (!HandleDropDownError(DropDownList3, err, "Du måste välja byggnad!"))
    return;
```

Comment: So simple so efficient. Thank you Sir, this was what i needed

Comment: Cheers, sometimes things are more simple than what we think. :-)

Comment: Can you help me please with something else?

Comment: Can't promise anything.. help you with what? If new question, please post it as new question and post link here.

Comment: is not new, is the same but i have now 3 DDl and 3 different errors, how i make to show into a single <p></p> all those 3 errors? :)

Comment: Sure, if I understand you correctly then see my edit, it should do what you asked for.

Comment: How do i make you a General or something, because i want to put a badge or something

Comment: Most one can give here is upvote and Accepting the answer, totaling in 25 reputation points which is nice. You can still upvote the answer by clicking the top arrow to the left. If and when you'll gain reputation yourself, you will be able to set bounty on this question then grant it to this answer, giving more reputation. However, your gratitude is better than any badge or reputation amount. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a [RequiredFieldValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hbw267h%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) :

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator
        id="rfvFavoriteCar"
        Text="Du måste välja Fordonstyp!"
        ControlToValidate="DropDownList1"
        Runat="server" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment Sir, I will take in consideration for the feature

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have a field selected, why not remove the empty selection line?

```
<asp:ListItem Text="" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        err.InnerHtml = "<span style='font: normal bold 11px/100% Arial, Verdana, Sans-Serif; color: Red'>Du måste välja Fordonstyp!</span>";
        err.visible = true;
        return;
    }
else
        err.visible = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I took your code modified it to work.  (at least what I think you are looking for)

```
   <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" CssClass="jump" AutoPostBack="true">
```

and here

```
if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 0)
{
    err.InnerHtml = "<span style='font: normal bold 11px/100% Arial, Verdana, Sans-Serif; color: Red'>Du måste välja Fordonstyp!</span>";
    return;
}else {err.InnerHtml = ""}
```